# Use JavaScript to validate a field in Shiny App

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I would like to validate a the a form on using JavaScript.  I know I can 
add an `onclick` method to an actionButton by providing an `onclick` argument like so:

```
textInput('timeField', "Time",'12:00')
actionButton('okButton', 
        'OK',
         onclick="function(){ if(!(/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-6][0-9])$/
                                 .test($('#timeField').val()))){
                                       alert('download time must be in 24 hour (HH:MM)
                                              fomrat.'); 
                                  return false; } }"))
```

However, the quote characters in the JavaScript function get translated to `&quot` or `&#39`, which cause a syntax error.  I've tried wrapping the string in `HTML()` but that doesn't seem to change this behavior.

Is there any way to include a raw string in the `onclick` argument and not have it transformed by Shiny?  (or maybe a better way to validate a form on the client side in a Shiny App?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) to do the form validation in JavaScript. I changed your JS function a little bit because I don't think the validation code there works. Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- HTML("
shinyjs.validate = function() {
  var regex = /([01]\\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\\d)/;
  if(!regex.test($('#timeField').val())) {
    alert('download time must be in 24 hour (HH:MM) format.');
  }
}
")

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
    textInput('timeField', "Time",'12:00'),
    actionButton('okButton', 'OK')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$okButton, {
      js$validate()
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution and a shinyjs looks like a handy package.  It's unfortunate that shiny does not natively support using JS code, which is a major oversight IMHO.  The risk with third party shiny packages (or any other framework) is keeping the third party packages up-to-date when Shiny eventually changes their API.

Comment: Shiny does support communicating with JS, that's how I was able to make the shinyjs package. It's just not super trivial and a bit verbose, so I decided to make a package to make that stuff easier. In general I agree with you, but in this particular case I highly doubt Shiny will drastically change how JS communication works and will probably not break shinyjs.  And if they do - I'm sure I'll know about it before big changes happen as I sometimes talk with the shiny dev team and I'm sure they'll let shiny package owners know before huge breaking changes. So in this case, it should be safe :)